# Leaflet map is either already initialized or map container is not found

Tags: javascript, ajax, import, leaflet

Hello friendly developers,

I have a problem with my leaflet map. I initialize like this in a file map.ts, and my page is working like a charm.

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster'
import { MAP_TITLE_LAYER, MAP_TITLE_ATTRIBUTION, MAP_TARGET } from '../../constants';

// @ts-ignore
import Popup from 'components/MapPopup/index.html.twig';

const markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
let markersData = [];

let map = L.map(MAP_TARGET);

const removeClassFromMarker = () =>{
    const markers = document.querySelectorAll('.leaflet-marker-icon');
    markers.forEach(marker => {
        marker.classList.remove('bring-to-front');
    });
}

export const initMap = (arrayDatas) => {
    if (document.querySelector('#leaflet')) {

        L.tileLayer(MAP_TITLE_LAYER, {
            detectRetina: true,
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: MAP_TITLE_ATTRIBUTION,
        }).addTo(map);

        if (arrayDatas.length) {
            arrayDatas.forEach(item => {
                const position = [
                    item.coordinates.lat,
                    item.coordinates.long,
                ];

                let icon = '';
                const status = item.status;
                switch (status) {
                    case 'excellent':
                        icon = '/assets/images/map/level-1.svg';
                        break;
                    case 'good':
                        icon = '/assets/images/map/level-2.svg';
                        break;
                    case 'average':
                        icon = '/assets/images/map/level-3.svg';
                        break;
                    case 'low':
                        icon = '/assets/images/map/level-4.svg';
                        break;
                    case 'very-bad':
                        icon = '/assets/images/map/level-5.svg';
                        break;
                    default:
                        icon = '/assets/images/map/default.svg'
                }

                const defaultIcon = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: icon,
                    iconSize: [30, 40],
                });
                markersData.push(L.latLng(position));

                // const marker = L.marker(position, { icon: defaultIcon }).on('click', onMarkerClick).bindPopup(Popup({
                const marker = L.marker(position, { icon: defaultIcon })
                .on('click', function(e){
                    removeClassFromMarker;
                    e.target._icon.classList.add('bring-to-front');
                })
                .bindPopup(Popup({
                    name: item.name,
                    localisation : item.localisation,
                    score : item.score,
                    visitors : item.visitors,
                    status : item.status,
                  }));
                markers.addLayer(marker);
            });

            map.addLayer(markers).on('click', function(e){
                removeClassFromMarker;
            });
            var bounds = L.latLngBounds(markersData)
            map.fitBounds(bounds)
            map.zoomControl.setPosition('bottomright');

        }
    }
}

export const deconstructMap = () => {
    markers.clearLayers();
    markersData = [];
}
```

But on my page, I also have an ajax search, where i am looking for some datas and i am refreshing my map by deconstructing it and calling again the function with rhe right datas, and it's also working well.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';
import { getEhpadScoreList, getEhpadList } from './searchEhpad.ajax';

// @ts-ignore
import ResultList from 'components/SearchItem/index.html.twig';
import { LOADER_CLASSNAME, MAP_TARGET } from '../constants';
import { initMap, deconstructMap } from './visitor/map';

const $searchResultContainer = document.getElementById('js-ehpad-search-result');

const minimumSizeTextInput:number = 2;

const dataArray = []

// Loader
const setLoaderOnInput = (item:HTMLInputElement):void =>{
    item.closest('.input-with-loader').classList.add(LOADER_CLASSNAME);
}
const removeLoaderOnInput = (item:HTMLInputElement):void =>{
    item.closest('.input-with-loader').classList.remove(LOADER_CLASSNAME);
}

// When searching
const InputSearchValue = async(e:any):Promise<void> => {
    if (e.target.value.length > minimumSizeTextInput){
        const getScore = Boolean(e.target.getAttribute('data-search-score'));
        try {
            setLoaderOnInput(e.target);
            const data:any = getScore?await getEhpadScoreList(e.target.value):await getEhpadList(e.target.value);
            $searchResultContainer.innerHTML = ResultList({
              items: data,
              translations : JS_TRANSLATION,
            });
            if (document.getElementById(MAP_TARGET)){
                deconstructMap();
                initMap(data);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } finally {
            removeLoaderOnInput(e.target);
        }
    }
}

const DebounceInputSearchValue = debounce(InputSearchValue, 500)

const initSearch = () => {
    const $searchInput = <HTMLInputElement>(document.getElementById('js-input-search-ehpad'));
    if($searchInput){
        $searchInput.addEventListener('input', DebounceInputSearchValue)
    }
}

export default initSearch;
```

But the problem is, now if i go on another page, I have an error saying that map container is not defined. I tried to move the line `let map = L.map(MAP_TARGET);` in my initMap function, but if i do that, my ajax search is not working, because i have an error saying that my map is already initialized (it's normal because i'm calling l.map twice).

I'm also thinking that maybe the error is coming from my import, if i could put a condition or something like this, maybe i could fix this issue.

I don't know how to errase the errors, in both case. It's either my map is initialized and i can't search or i have other functionnalities on others pages blocked, i need help !

EDIT : I fixed my issue by adding these two lines

```
const $mapContainer = document.getElementById(MAP_TARGET);
let map = $mapContainer !== null && L.map($mapContainer);
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

From your description:

> if i go on another page, I have an error saying that map container is not defined

And:

> maybe the error is coming from my import, if i could put a condition or something like this

It sounds like you import your `map.ts` file in the other page as well? (Or possibly indirectly by importing another script that itself imports `map.ts`, e.g. if you also import your search script)

Then the first error message is because in that page, you do not have a `MAP_TARGET` element, but since the code in `map.ts` file is executed, it tries to find it to instantiate your map.

Of course, the proper solution is to **not** import your `map.ts` file in pages which are not supposed to have a map.

If for some reason that is too complex, a possible workaround could be indeed to add a condition before instantiating the map.

For example, explicitly look for your `MAP_TARGET` element first:

```
const $mapContainer = document.getElementById(MAP_TARGET);
let map = $mapContainer && L.map($mapContainer);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer ! Yes, I have a global app.ts file that is imported on every page, and I included the  functions like this ```import { initMap } from './visitor/map'; import initSearch from './modules/searchEhpad';``` on it. But on the files, I'm always checking if the element exist before calling the functions, that's what i don't understand. I tried your solution, but it didn't work, I still have a map container not found on other pages as well

Comment: My bad the check condition was slightly incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
var map = null;
function view_map_area() {

    if (map !== undefined && map !== null)
    {
        map.off();
        map.remove();
    }
    
    map = L.map('map').setView([centerLat,centerLong], 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are using ".map()" of "rxjs", also may face this error. How I solved it is, importing "map" module of "rxjs" as

```
import {map as rxjsMap} from 'rxjs/operators';
```